# Any way to Format or Write code in Google Document

Tags: formatting, document, document-library

I want to keep the snippets of code in My Google Document but when i paste the code
it looks weird . Is there any way to format the code like we have in stackoverflow

where the code is in colors

Comment: use an SVN space instead (go on Google Code)

Comment: can you give me the link , i could not find what r u talking aboout.
I searched google as well but could not find what is SVN

Comment: Not about programming, just highlighting a document

Comment: Try asking on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste it into a .doc/docx will have the same indents and colours

Comment: I tried pasting code from stackoverflow to .docx , formatting is there but color is not there